# Using Python's Regular Expression to Insert Symbol Between Certain Characters

Tags: python, regex, replace, insert

I am making a math program that allows the user to input an equation and the program will solve it.  I am trying to make it as user friendly as possible. I want the user to be able to easily type an equation in without having to worry about adding the multiplication symbol between every instance of multiplication.

*Here is an example:*

User input: `y=xy+yz` Program output: `y=x*y+y*z`

I have been able to accomplish this easily using Python's re module as follows:

```
equation = "y=xy+yz"
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuvet])([xyzuvet])",r"\1*\2", equation)  # x,y,z,u,v,e, and t and variables and constants the user can use in their equation.
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuvet])([xyzuvet])",r"\1*\2", equation)  # Must run twice in the event the equation looks something like y=xyzxyz
```

However I run into a problem when I introduce a special function such as `y=yexp(x)`.  When I run the code above, I will get an output of `y=y*e*xp(x)`.

I later updated my code to account for pi:

```
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuve]|pi)([xyzuve]|pi)",r"\1*\2", equation)
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuve]|pi)([xyzuve]|pi)",r"\1*\2", equation)
```

I was thinking I could use a similar approach from above to match `exp` and prevent it from adding a `*` between the 'e' and 'x' as follows:

```
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuve]|pi|exp)([xyzuve]|pi|exp)",r"\1*\2", equation)
equation = re.sub(r"([xyzuve]|pi|exp)([xyzuve]|pi|exp)",r"\1*\2", equation)
```

I thougt by adding `exp` in the same way I did `pi`, it would work; but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Is there a way to treat `exp` and other functions that also contain x,y,z,u,v,t, and e as a whole?

*Here are some examples of what I want an input to look like:*

In: `y=eexp(xyz)`  out: `y=e*exp(x*y*z)`

In: `y=pifrexp(yt)`  out: `y=pi*frexp(y*t)`

In: `y=sin(x)exp(y)`  out:`y=sin(x)*exp(y)`

Comment: put `exp` and `pi` first.

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately the same problem occurs.

Comment: Because of the `re.sub` a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to produce what you want:

```
equation = re.sub(r"([)xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)([xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)\b",r"\1*\2", equation)
equation = re.sub(r"([)xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)([xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)\b",r"\1*\2", equation)
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> eqns = ('y=eexp(xyz)', 'y=pifrexp(yt)', 'y=sin(x)exp(y)')
>>> for equation in eqns:
...     equation = re.sub(r"([)xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)([xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)\b",r"\1*\2", equation)
...     equation = re.sub(r"([)xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)([xyzuvet]|pi|exp|frexp)\b",r"\1*\2", equation)
...     print equation
... 
y=e*exp(x*y*z)
y=pi*frexp(y*t)
y=sin(x)*exp(y)
```

Comment: Your solution works well until I try something like `y= eexp(xyzzzz)`. My output becomes `y=e*exp(xyzz*z*z)`.  **EDIT:** If I repeat the `re.sub` many more times, it works, but not exactly the best approach.

Comment: @anubhava Yes I have. It was missing the `e`, so no `*` appeared between `e` and another character. When I add 'e' back to the list, same problem occurs.

Comment: So `pifrexp(yte)` should become `pi*frexp(y*t*e)` ?

Comment: When I run `(?!^)(?=(?<!fr)(?:fr)?exp|sin|pi|(?<=[txyzuve])[txyzuve])` for `pifrexp(yte)`, I get `pi*fre*xp(y*t*e)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use look arounds to as

```
(?<=[xyzuvtf])(?=[xyzuvtf])|(?=exp)|(?<=pi)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rP4iV7/1)

Comment: Isn't it adding a `*` in `frexp`?

Comment: That is a good point. `f` is not a variable used in my program so it doesn't matter, but good catch.

Answer (score 1):

This regex based on lookarounds works for all your test cases:

```
(?!^)(?=(?<!fr)(?:fr)?exp|sin|pi|(?<=[xtyzuv]|e(?!xp))[etxyzuv])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO4dH5/2)